# IHttpActionResult - Returning List of anonymous objects

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

In Web API 2.0 , I am trying to return ***IHttpActionResult*** from a Get() method.  When I am returning ***Ok(singleAnonymousObject)*** everything is working fine.  But when I am trying to return ***OK( listOfAnonymousObject )*** I ma getting below error.  I have also included code to explain above scenario.

**Error :**

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at WriteArrayOf_x003C__x003E_f__AnonymousType0OfintstringToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Below is my setup.

**Web API Configuration:**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultRoute","api/{controller}/{id}",new  {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, ProductUOW>();
        container.RegisterType<ProductContext, ProductContext>();
        configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseWebApi(configuration);
    }
```

**ValuesController**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var r = productUow.Customers.Get();
            var result = r.Where(rr => rr.Id > 0).Select(n => new
            {
                IdVal = n.Id,
                TEstName = n.Name
            }).FirstOrDefault();
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Upon invoking *http://localhost:61569/api/values* I am getting single JSon object back. But the moment I try to return list I am getting the said error message.

**Problem**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
     var r = productUow.Customers.Get();
     var result = r.Where(rr => rr.Id > 0).Select(n => new
     {
          IdVal = n.Id,
          TEstName = n.Name
     }).ToList(); //Causing trouble here
     return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: This error is thrown when trying to serialize to XML. If don't care about XML serialization and working only with JSON - specify _content-type: application/json_  (with postman for example) and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  Alternatively I removed XmlFormatter from 'configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes' and now only JSon results are being return.

Answer (score 0):

Web Api 2 support these action result types:

- `HttpResponseMessage`
- `IHttpActionResult`
- `Void`
- `Other type`

May be, you can use Other Types and Task.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<CustomResponseModel> Test()
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```